# How to have a subreport with a table that has a dynamic amount of columns in Telerik reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I have a Report that is made with Telerik reporting. This report displays information for all given weekdays in a month (e.g. All Mondays in July 2017) in a table. The columns of the table are the days, the rows are the data associated with the dates.

The amount of times a certain day falls inside a month varies, so I need to have the ability to define the amount of columns the table needs to have based on the requested data. How would I do this?

Here a mock of how it should be displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the reportnames are `MainReport` and `SubReport`:

In the `MainReport` add the following code:

```
public static ReportSource SetReportSourceForSubreport(object data)
{
    var report = new SubReport(data);
    var repSource = new InstanceReportSource
    {
        ReportDocument = report
    };

    return repSource;
}
```

Now add a subreport to the main report via the Visual Studio Report Designer and set the ReportSource to `= MyNameSpace.MainReport.SetReportSourceForSubreport(Fields.Data)`. Make sure that `Data` is available in the datasource of the main report.

In your `SubReport` you will now need a constructor that accepts the data. First call the `InitializeComponent()` method, and then generate your table by code, adding the amount of columns and rows needed.

```
public SubReport(object data)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create and add table to report body
    var table = CreateTable(data);
    this.detail.Items.Add(table);
}
```

On how the generate a table by code, read the following page and associated articles for a detailed explanation. https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/table-understanding-cells-rows-columns

A small example on how to generate a table with code:

```
private Table CreateTable(Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
    ////
    // New table instance
    ////
    _requiredColumns = data.Count + 1;
    Table table = new Table()
    {
        Name = "tableDay",
        Docking = DockingStyle.Fill,
        Location = new PointU(Unit.Cm(0D), Unit.Cm(0D)),
        Size = new SizeU(Unit.Cm(17D), Unit.Cm(5D)),
        RowHeadersPrintOnEveryPage = true
    };

    table.Bindings.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Binding("DataSource", "= Fields.Rows"));

    for (int i = 0; i < _requiredColumns; i++)
    {
        table.Body.Columns.Add(new TableBodyColumn(Unit.Cm(_columnWidth)));
    }

    ////
    // Add headers
    ////
    table.ColumnGroups.Add(new TableGroup
    {
        Name = "columnLeftMost",
        ReportItem = new TextBox { Name = "textBoxHours", Value = "Hours" }
    });

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        table.ColumnGroups.Add(new TableGroup
        {
            Name = "column" + item.Key,
            ReportItem = new TextBox { Name = "textBoxTitleDay" + item.Key, Value = item.Key }
        });
    }

    ////
    // Add data rows
    ////

    var tableGroup28 = new TableGroup() { Name = "tableGroup280" };
    tableGroup28.Groupings.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Grouping(null));
    table.RowGroups.Add(tableGroup28);

    table.Body.Rows.Add(new TableBodyRow(Unit.Cm(ROWHEIGHT)));

    List<ReportItemBase> list = new List<ReportItemBase>();

    for (int i = 0; i < _requiredColumns; i++)
    {
        var tb = new TextBox
        {
            Name = "textBox" + i,
            Value = i == 0 ? "= Fields.DayTimeFriendly" : "= Fields.RowValues"
        };

        list.Add(tb);
        table.Body.SetCellContent(0, i, tb);
    }

    table.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());

    return table;
}
```